# Link terms on page to Wikipedia articles in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

While browsing I came across [this blog post](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/using-wikipedia-api-demo-source-code-example/3076/) about using the [Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) from [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), to link a single search term to it's definition. At the end of the blog post the author mentions possible extensions including:

> A plugin which auto links terms to Wikipedia articles.

This fits the bill perfectly for a project requirement I'm working on, but sadly I lack the programming skills to extend [the original source code](http://www.labnol.org/assets/images/wikipedia-json.html). What I'd like is to have a pure JavaScript snippet I can add to a webpage, that links all the terms on that webpage that have an article on an internal wiki to that wiki.

I know this might be asking for much, but the code looks like it's nearly there, and I'd be willing to add a bounty if anyone will do the remaining work for that virtual credit.. ;) I also suspect this might be of value to a few others, as I've seen similar requests but no working implementation (that's a mere JavaScript (and therefore portable) library/snippet include).

Here's a sample of the original source code, I hope anyone is able to add to this or point me to what I'd need to add if I were to implement this myself (in which case I'll share the code if I manage to put something together).

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var spellcheck = function (data) {
    var found = false; var url=''; var text = data [0];
    if (text != document.getElementById ('spellcheckinput').value)
        return;
    for (i=0; i<data [1].length; i++) {
        if (text.toLowerCase () == data [1] [i].toLowerCase ()) {
            found = true;
            url ='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + text;
            document.getElementById ('spellcheckresult').innerHTML = '<b style="color:green">Correct</b> - <a target="_top" href="' + url + '">link</a>';
        }
    }
    if (! found)
        document.getElementById ('spellcheckresult').innerHTML = '<b style="color:red">Incorrect</b>';
};

var getjs = function (value) {
    if (! value)
        return;
    url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='+value+'&format=json&callback=spellcheck';
    document.getElementById ('spellcheckresult').innerHTML = 'Checking ...';
    var elem = document.createElement ('script');
    elem.setAttribute ('src', url);
    elem.setAttribute ('type','text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName ('head') [0].appendChild (elem);
};--></script>
<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false"> 
<p>Enter a word - <input id="spellcheckinput" onkeyup="getjs (this.value);" type="text"> <span id="spellcheckresult"></span></p></form>
```

---

**Update**
As pointed out in the comments, both the time it would take to link all words and how to handle multiple word spanning article names were concerns of mine as well..

I'd think starting with single word articles would already cover a large percentage of the use cases, with maybe some performance benefits gained when skipping the 500 most common words in the English language, but still I'm uncertain how feasible this approach will be..

On the upside however this would all be client side, and some delay in linking terms is fully acceptable.

Alternatively searching for terms the mouse is hovering over / selected might be acceptable as well, but I'm unsure if this would decrease or increase complexity..

---

**Update 2**

'Pointy' explained below that this functionality could be achieved by altering some fairly standard highlighting scripts, after having obtained a list of article topics from `api.php?action=query&list=allpages`.
To reinterate: we're using an internal wiki, so the list of articles is likely limited, non ambiguous and domain specific enough to overcome some of the expected problems in matching words.

Since we've had some good suggestions so far, and a few workable ideas, I'm starting a bounty to see if I can get a few answers on this..

Comment: How is the script supposed to know what terms (words? phrases?) in the page have articles on the wiki?

Comment: The provided code checks if an article with the given name exists on Wikipedia. It has nothing to do with linking terms on your page to Wiki articles, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah I see - well if the "local wiki" supports the JSONP callback then he could certainly do it that way. I have to wonder how you'd handle multi-word Wiki entries - how would you know what multi-word sequences to check? Check all of them? How long will all those wiki HTTP search transactions take?

Comment: If he automagically wants to link all the terms on his page to Wiki articles, he'd have to run a HTTP request for every single word on the page... That's not good.
Plus, as Pointy says, how would the script find multi-word Wiki articles? Basically, it won't.

Comment: What you could do is check if a Wiki article exists, when a user has his or her mouse over a term for more than, say, 2 seconds, so it will only have to make do a request for a small amount of terms. But the user won't immediately see if something has a related Wiki article, before s/he takes the time to keep his mouse on a certain term for 2 seconds...

Comment: If the question-asker has control over the Wiki, then one possibility would be to make a Wiki API that would return a current "dictionary" of terms. That way the script could fetch one big block of words, and then just search for those on each page. This script: http://tinyurl.com/6rk6ae could be adapted to add the markup.

Comment: Fortunately, the API already offers `api.php?action=query&list=allpages`, see: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&aplimit=50 This could optionally be cached to prevent loading the list for each request..

Comment: Aesthetically, this stuff sounds dreadful. Someone reading a page on your site will have every other word with a link to a wikipedia article??? .... which is just as visually distracting as linking all the nontrivial words to advertisements

Comment: @Paul: No. We're using an internal wiki with a (very) limited set of articles, that serve an educational purpose for our students. Due to this limited set of articles only a few words would be linked. This eliminates both the need to select which words to link and how to handle duplicates (there simply wont be any duplicates).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this might help:

Assuming very simple HTML/Text like so:

```
<div id="theText">Testing the auto link system here...</div>
```

And two very small scripts.

`dictionary.js` sets up your list of your terms.  My thought was that this could be generated in php by querying the articles database if you wanted.  It also can be loaded cross domain (as it sets `window.termsRE`).  If you don't need to generate the list from the database, you could also manually put it with `termlinker.js`.

This code that generates the RegExp assumes that your `terms` array contains properly formatted strings to match using Regular Expressions, so be sure to use `\\` to escape `[]\.?*+|(){}^&`

```
// dictionary.js - define some terms
var terms = ['testing', 'auto link'];
window.termsRE = new RegExp("\\b("+terms.join("|")+")\\b",'gi');
```

`termlinker.js` is just a simple regexp search replace on the defined terms.  It could be an inline `<script>` too. requires that the `dictionary.js` has been loaded before you run it.

```
// termlinker.js - add some tags
var element = document.getElementById("theText");

element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(termsRE, function(term) {
  return "<a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+escape(term)+"'>"+term+"</a>";
});
```

This simply searches for any words in the terms array and replaces them with a link to the term.  Of course, it will also match properties and values inside HTML tags, which could break your markup a little.

All thrown together you get [this (jsbin preview)](http://jsbin.com/oqopi/2)

---

### Using the API

Based off of the "minimum case" from before, here is the code sample for using the API to receive the list of words directly and [the jsbin preview](http://jsbin.com/oqopi/5)

```
// Utility Function
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  if (!arguments.callee.sRE) {
    var specials = [
      '/', '.', '*', '+', '?', '|',
      '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\'
    ];
    arguments.callee.sRE = new RegExp(
      '(\\' + specials.join('|\\') + ')', 'g'
    );
  }
  return text.replace(arguments.callee.sRE, '\\$1');
};

// JSONP Callback for receiving the API
function receiveAPI(data) {
  var terms = [];
  if (!data || !data['query'] || !data['query']['allpages']) return false;  
  var pages = data.query.allpages
  for (var x in pages) {
    terms.push(RegExp.escape(pages[x].title));
  }
  window.termsRE = new RegExp("\\b("+terms.reverse().join("|")+")\\b",'gi');
  linkterms();
}  

function linkterms() {
  var element = document.getElementById("theText");

  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(termsRE, function(term) {
    return "<a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+escape(term)+"'>"+term+"</a>";
  });
}


// the apfrom=testing can be removed, it is only there so that
// we can get some useful terms near "testing" to work with.
// we are limited to 500 terms for the purpose of this demo:
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&aplimit=500&format=json&callback=receiveAPI' + '&apfrom=testing';
var elem = document.createElement('script');
elem.setAttribute('src', url);
elem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild (elem);
```

Comment: Nice start, any chance you can combine this with the json `api.php?action=query&list=allpages` call, or another `api.php` query to get topic titles? I'm looking for something pure Javascript, so PHP isn't really an option.. (As pointed out above, I hardly know Javascript, so I need more than an a start..)

Comment: Great work, thanks! On the downside howver, I found out I now have to upgrade our local wiki instance for API compatability..

Comment: @gnarf - Is there any manner to bypass the "**we are limited to 500 terms for the purpose of this demo**"-limit? I'm looking mimic the full wikipedia-functionality of auto-hyperlinking to wikipedia articles. --- Thanks a lot. --- I also started a post to auto-hyperlink to *predefined* Wikipedia-articles, so that there is no redirection to ambiguity pages: [Auto-hyperlink every occurence of a certain word (or word sequence) to predefined URL (non-ambiguous); but not show full URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398112), a post which still needs some thinking.