# Auto-hyperlink every occurence of a certain word (or word sequence) to predefined URL (non-ambiguous); but not show full URL

Tags: javascript, wikipedia

***Similar to:*** *[Search For Words, Replace With Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583303/search-for-words-replace-with-links). However, I would rather not have the full hyperlink's URL visible, but instead have only the appearance of a hyperlink visible to the end-user. --- I also can't figure out how to use the `replace()`-JS-function, like used in the following post: [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript), for this same specific issue. --- Also similar to a JS-question: [Link terms on page to Wikipedia articles in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347992/link-terms-on-page-to-wikipedia-articles-in-pure-javascript?rq=1), but I guess the answer given there can not, up front, differentiate between ambiguous terms.*

## How to auto-link every occurence of *single words* or *word sequences* to their respective predefined URL's?

In (a) certain HTML-page(s), is it possible to:

- Predefine manually; or automatically (Cf: ***[Wiki-api](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)***) a list of single words and their respective (i.c. Wikipedia)-articles;
- such that every (such coupled) word in a document automatically receives the predefined link to the respective (i.c. Wikipedia)-article.

*EXAMPLE*:

**(1)** Wherever the word *cell* occurs, this word should receive the link: [...wiki/cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell), to give the following result: a [cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell) is but a [cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell).

---

So, what I actually would like is to mimic what is actually happening within any [Wikipedia-article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) itself (although I don't know whether this is automated there).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO is not for broad questions, suggestions, or help finding a plugin.   Please review:  ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tags should be used to represent the content of the question. I don't see anything mentioned about JavaScript in the question.  Edited tags.  Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to create this document?

Comment: @grovesNL - Thank you for your question: I now specified the document-type in the question: "ordinary" `HTML`. --- Or did you mean perhaps to ask my *[CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)*? Me, specifically, I am using Drupal to create this `HTML`-article. --- @Sparky - Thank you for your edit. I think one might somehow use a *JS* for a `replace()`-function similar functions, as referred to now in the question. --- I also edited my question, in the hope to be as clear and to-the-point as possible about its technicalities; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the question you linked, it's pretty easy to modify it to achieve your goal. So first assuming we have a list of phrase and links like this:

```
var words = [
    { word: 'foo', link: 'http://www.something.com' },
    { word: 'Something Else', link: 'http://www.something.com/else' ]
];
```

We can iterate over that list replacing any occurrence in the document, but including the word we are searching for in the text we are inserting. I've added in a tooltip to this too to show an example of what else you can do.

```
$(function() {
    $.each(words,
        function() {
            var searchWord = this.word;
            var link = this.link;
            $('body:contains("' + searchWord + '")').each(function() {
                var newHtml = $(this).html().replace(searchWord, 
                    '<a class="wikilink" title="here is a link to Wikipedia" href="'+link+'">' + searchWord + '</a>');
                $(this).html(newHtml);
            });
        }
    );
});
```

And a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yxhk1fcd/10/

Comment: Thank you very much for this exquisite answer. I like very much how you included `title="here is a link to Wikipedia"` as well. --- Your answer has advantage over the answer given in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347992/link-terms-on-page-to-wikipedia-articles-in-pure-javascript, since your answer can include predefined URL's, which seems necessary to me when wanting directly to link to a specific page (e.g. *Cell_biology*), without being directed to the (e.g. *Cell*) disambiguation page (which would be expected behavior using the answer from the hyperlinked post.

Comment: Are you sure it's an endless loop and not just a race condition? For example, does this script kick off some other script which in turn causes this one to run again? Also, is this script wrapped in a document ready check `$(function() { code-here });`?

Comment: Step through the code and see exactly what is happening. Let it run for a second then pause in the debugger.

Comment: It may be preferable for you to only replace words in certain areas of your page. To change that, just replace `body:contains` with a different selector. So if your text block was wrapped in a div with class `blog` you would use `.blog:contains`

Comment: Like I said above, it will work if you use a specific selector. Wrap your entire content in a `div` and use that instead.

Comment: I removed my comments, thank you very much, this indeed solves the waiting / hanging time. --- Might I perhaps ask for some help on another issue? When having the following *HTML*: `A stem cell is a kind of cell, but also a cell.`; and the following *Javascript*-"array": `{
        word: 'cell',
        link: 'http://www.something.com/else'
    }, {
        word: 'stem cell',
        link: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stem_cell'
    }`; there seems to be a problem in recognizing `stem cell`, as well as with recognizing both of the other `cell`'s...

Comment: Do stem cell first, then cell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does give partly the desired result, in this simple case. --- However, the second instance of cell is not hyperlinked. --- So, especially for large documents too, could you suggest any new way to take for improving the code, when working with large files, containing many terms?